# issue with saving instance state in android

Tags: android, view, state

I wrote the code as below for saving state of textview:

```
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle b){
        System.out.println("save");
         TextView tv1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text1);

        b.putString(TEXTVIEW_STATE_KEY, tv1.getText().toString());
        super.onSaveInstanceState(b);
    }
```

then i retrieve as follows inside onCreate

```
if(savedInstanceState!=null && savedInstanceState.containsKey(TEXTVIEW_STATE_KEY));
        {
            System.out.println("hello");
       text=savedInstanceState.getString(TEXTVIEW_STATE_KEY);

        tv.setText(text);
        }
```

TEXTVIEW_STATE_KEY is a String constant.But while starting application it is throwing nullpointer exception in line

```
text=savedInstanceState.getString(TEXTVIEW_STATE_KEY);
```

Anyone having idea? plz help.

Comment: recheck line . becuause inside if(savedInstanceState!=null) it can not be null .  in tv.setText(text) , tv might be null

Comment: @ShailendraRajawat Thanks.But in tv i m setting it by findViewById() function and it is not null.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Semicolon at end of 'if' statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14112515/semicolon-at-end-of-if-statement)

Answer (score 1):

Its because you are storing NULL in your Bundle while saving the save of the TextView. TextView should have some value before storing its state. Like this,

```
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle b){
         super.onSaveInstanceState(b);       
         System.out.println("save");
         TextView tv1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text1);
         tv1.setText("saving the value");
         b.putString(TEXTVIEW_STATE_KEY, tv1.getText().toString());
    }
```

Comment: thanks buddy.but i have already set text inside oncreate.there is a logic which i m ensuring textview has text value in it.No problem with that.Just it is not working and showing NP in line as i told in my question

Comment: one problem can be this super.onSaveInstanceState(b); you are calling this at last which should be at top of the method.

Answer (score 0):

Very old question, but the answer is pretty simple...There is a semicolon (`;`) at the end of your if condition.