# Why is this if statement always returning true?

Tags: java, string, arraylist

Suppose: list = ["be", "be", "is", "not", "or", "question", "that", "the", "to", "to"]

```
public static void removeDuplicates(ArrayList<String> list) {
    for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        String s = list.get(i);
        for(int j = 0; j < list.size() - 1; j++) {
            String s2 = list.get(j);
            if(s2.equals(s)); {
                list.remove(j + 1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I debug it, `s2.equals(s)` seems to be returning true all the time when s2 and s does not equal to each other at all. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: At the initial step, i=0 and j=0.

Comment: Remove the semicolon: `if(s2.equals(s));`

Comment: please remove the `;` after if (..) if(s2.equals(s));

Comment: Just as an additional hint: You might consider using a Set instead of an ArrayList, so you do not have to deal with duplicates at all.

Comment: See this one : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203984/how-do-i-remove-repeated-elements-from-arraylist

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the semicolon:

```
        if(s2.equals(s)); {
```

Should be

```
        if(s2.equals(s)) {
```

EDIT: Explanantion: In your code, you have an empty statement after the `if`, and so the block will be executed regardless of the comparison result:

```
public static void removeDuplicates(ArrayList<String> list) {
    for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        String s = list.get(i);
        for(int j = 0; j < list.size() - 1; j++) {
            String s2 = list.get(j);
            if(s2.equals(s))
                ; // <-- conditional
            {     // <-- unconditional
                list.remove(j + 1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I didnt realize I put semiconlon there... Thank you.
Why is semicolon always returning the if statement true?
Just curious.

Comment: It isn't. The semicolon just stands for an empty statement and terminates your then-clause. You might want to have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14112515/semicolon-at-end-of-if-statement

Answer (score 1):

You're testing elements against themselves too and you have a semicolon effectively removing the `if`. You probably want

```
if (i!=j && s2.equals(s)) {
```

Answer (score 1):

You should start your second loop from `i+1`, because in every iteration for `j` loop the `i` value will be equal to `j` and it will satisfy the equals condition ....

```
public static void removeDuplicates(ArrayList<String> list) 
{
  for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) 
  {
    String s = list.get(i);
    for(int j = i+1; j < list.size(); j++) 
    {
        String s2 = list.get(j);
        if(s2.equals(s))             
        {   
           list.remove(j + 1);
           j--; //Subtract one as j+1 element is removed from list and index changes
        }

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Also the semicolon needs to be removed.

Comment: what peter said. Also, list.remove should remove `j`, not `j+1`

Comment: @Ploutox if `j` element is removed then the loop should break, because if the same element is occuring furthur in the array then the next element which will be removed might not be duplicate or the wrong element will be removed....

Answer (score 1):

You have an extra semicolon. Do as follows:

```
if(s2.equals(s))             
    list.remove(j + 1);
```

and this change should work.