# if and else statements not working as intended

Tags: java, if-statement

I am making a really simple program, mostly to learn the `if/else` statements. The program is made to figure out if you have chosen a correct date.

The program is intended to work as follows:

- Start the program, it gives you an instruction to type in a month
  using numbers.
- If you type in a number between 1 and 12, it will give you another,
  similar instruction, but for days.
- If you have chosen another number, or a word, it should say "month
  wrong". Depending on which month you have chosen, you will have
  different numbers of days that are "correct". If you have chosen
  right, it should say "Date correct".
- If you have chosen a date that is not correct, it should say "Wrong
  day for the chosen month".

The problem is, that if you type for example 15 in the month section, it states

> MonthWrongWrongdayinthemonthWrongdayinthemonth

instead of just

> month wrong

Is this because I have `if/else` statements inside of other `if/else` statements? I have tried searching for this everywhere but I can not figure out what's wrong..

This is a link to a picture of the console when I try to run the app.

[Picture of console](https://gyazo.com/c901608b0d9c09fceba91aa672ae5c4f)

Please excuse the Swedish words.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DateChecker111 {

    public static void main (String args[]) {

        Scanner scanner1 = new Scanner(System.in);

        int Manad, Dag;
        System.out.print("Ange Månad>");

        Manad = scanner1.nextInt();
        if (Manad > 0 && Manad < 13) {
        }
        else {
            System.out.print("Felaktig Månad");
        }

        if (Manad == 1 || Manad == 3 || Manad == 5 || Manad == 7 || Manad == 8 || Manad == 10 || Manad == 12) {
            System.out.print("Ange Dag>");
            Dag = scanner1.nextInt();
            if (Dag > 0 && Dag < 32); 
            System.out.print("Korrekt Datum");
        }
        else {
                System.out.print("Felaktig Dag i Månaden");
        }

        if (Manad == 2) {
            System.out.print("Ange Dag");
            Dag = scanner1.nextInt();
            if (Dag > 0 && Dag < 29); 
            System.out.print("Korrekt Datum");
        }
        else {
            System.out.print("Felaktig Dag i Månaden");
        }

        if (Manad == 4 || Manad == 6 || Manad == 9 || Manad == 11) {
            System.out.println("Ange Dag");
            Dag = scanner1.nextInt();
            if (Dag > 0 && Dag < 31);
            System.out.print("Korrekt Datum");
        } 
        else {
            System.out.print("Felaktig Dag i Månaden");

            scanner1.close();

        }
    }


}
```

Comment: [This seems to be fairly prevalent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14112515/semicolon-at-end-of-if-statement) in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is your code formatted better so you can see the mistakes you've made. There are 3 `if` statements that end in `;`, instead of a `{` as you intended. With the code formatted as it is now, you should notice that instead of a bunch of nested `if` statements, you have several `if` statements that will all be run, even if the first one fails. This is what you are seeing. To fix this, remove the `;` at the end of the `if` statements, and add `{`. (I marked the bad ifs with `// BAD IF`)

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DateChecker111 {

    public static void main (String args[]) {

        Scanner scanner1 = new Scanner(System.in);

        int Manad, Dag;
        System.out.print("Ange Månad>");

        Manad = scanner1.nextInt();
        if (Manad > 0 && Manad < 13) {
        }
        else {
            System.out.print("Felaktig Månad");
        }

        if (Manad == 1 || Manad == 3 || Manad == 5 || Manad == 7 || Manad == 8 || Manad == 10 || Manad == 12) {
            System.out.print("Ange Dag>");
            Dag = scanner1.nextInt();

            // BAD IF
            if (Dag > 0 && Dag < 32);

            System.out.print("Korrekt Datum");
        } else {
            System.out.print("Felaktig Dag i Månaden");
        }

        if (Manad == 2) {
            System.out.print("Ange Dag");
            Dag = scanner1.nextInt();

            // BAD IF
            if (Dag > 0 && Dag < 29);

            System.out.print("Korrekt Datum");
        } else {
            System.out.print("Felaktig Dag i Månaden");
        }

        if (Manad == 4 || Manad == 6 || Manad == 9 || Manad == 11) {
            System.out.println("Ange Dag");
            Dag = scanner1.nextInt();

            // BAD IF
            if (Dag > 0 && Dag < 31);

            System.out.print("Korrekt Datum");
        } else {
            System.out.print("Felaktig Dag i Månaden");

            scanner1.close();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that did indeed fix the original problem! But now, I have another one...

The part that starts with if (Manad == 1 || .....) works, meaning that if I enter any of the numbers in that part, the application runs as it should. 

But, if I enter 2, 4, 6, 9 or 11, it terminates immidiately. 

I guess that this is because it only checks with the first "Manad" and not with the second and third...

Any tips on this aswell? 

@forgivenson

Comment: Check the nesting of your if statements again. Your `if(Manad == 2)` is inside your `if(Manad == 1 || ....)`, which doesn't allow `Manad == 2`, so that if statement will never be reached. There could be other issues too. Make sure your code is indented properly, so you can see issues like this more easily.

Comment: I figured it out! Used an else if statement on (Manad == 2) and (Manad == 4 ...)

Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 2):

The real problem here, and the root of all your troubles, is that you consistently end `if` statements with semicolons. For example, you write:

```
if (Dag > 0 && Dag < 32); 
    System.out.print("Korrekt Datum");
```

This is equivalent to having no `if` statement at all!

An `if` statement has the following form:

```
if (condition)
    statement
```

and an `if-else` statement has the following form:

```
if (condition)
    statement
else
    anotherStatement
```

Notice that I left off the semicolons and braces. That was deliberate. In either of those forms, `statement` and `anotherStatement` can either be a single statement ending in a semicolon, or a `Block` consisting of some number of `statements` inside braces. So when you end your `if` statement with a semicolon, you're actually writing

```
if (condition)
    ;
```

In the example code I quoted above, you're writing

```
if (Dag > 0 && Dag < 32)
    ; 
System.out.print("Korrekt Datum");
```

Take out the extra semicolons and your life will be happier.

Answer (score 1):

The execution flow of the appellation doesn't stop because a branch of the if/else has been executed, it will go on to execute the second if/else the result of which will also be output.

Answer (score 1):

Your second if-statement gets executed regardless whether the first one succeeds or not. To fix that, you can add

```
    return;
```

right after

```
    System.out.println("Felaktig Manad");
```

Also, be very careful with semicolons (;). There are multiple cases where you use a semicolon right after an if-statement which causes the if-statement to do nothing at all (it essentially gets skipped completely). Replace those semicolons with closing curly brackets (}).
Depending on your IDE you can probably hit crtl+I so it indents your code automatically and you can see clearly what it does.

Answer (score 0):

You have issues with your braces, see this code:
if

```
(Manad == 1 || Manad == 3 || Manad == 5 || Manad == 7 || Manad == 8 || Manad == 10 || Manad == 12) {
        System.out.print("Ange Dag>");
        Dag = scanner1.nextInt();
        if (Dag > 0 && Dag < 32); 
            System.out.print("Korrekt Datum");
            }
            else {
                System.out.print("Felaktig Dag i Månaden");
        }
```

Your first closing brace `}` actually closes the main if. The code could be seen as:

```
if (Manad == 1 || Manad == 3 || Manad == 5 || Manad == 7 || Manad == 8 || Manad == 10 || Manad == 12) {
    System.out.print("Ange Dag>");
    Dag = scanner1.nextInt();
    if (Dag > 0 && Dag < 32); 
        System.out.print("Korrekt Datum");   
}
else {
    System.out.print("Felaktig Dag i Månaden");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the semicolon with bracket in this line:

```
if (Dag > 0 && Dag < 32);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're Gavin said, the execution doesn't stop just because you enter a else statement, it keeps going from that point.
If you want it to work as you expect it to you either have to put the code that should run only if the if-statement is true inside the if-block or introduce a return statement.

```java
if(foo == 1) {
  if(bar == 2 {
    //Do something
  }
  else {
    //bar is not 2
  }
}
else {
  //foo is not 1
}
```

or

```
if(foo == 1) {
}
else {
  //foo is not 1
  return;
}
if(bar == 2 {
  //Do something
}
else {
  //bar is not 2
  return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your if(Manad == 2) inside the the else statement that belongs to if(Manad == 1..... Also put the if (Manad == 4.... inside the else statement of (Manad ==2). I did some comments and removed some brackets.

```
    Scanner scanner1 = new Scanner(System.in);

int Manad, Dag;
System.out.print("Ange Månad>");

Manad = scanner1.nextInt();
if (Manad > 0 && Manad < 13) {

    // you're not doing something here
}
else { 
    System.out.print("Felaktig Månad");
}

if (Manad == 1 || Manad == 3 || Manad == 5 || Manad == 7 || Manad == 8 || Manad == 10 || Manad == 12) {
    System.out.print("Ange Dag>");
    Dag = scanner1.nextInt();
    if (Dag > 0 && Dag < 32) {
        System.out.print("Korrekt Datum");
    }
}
else { // called if Manad != 1,3,5,7,8,10, or 12
    System.out.print("Felaktig Dag i Månaden");
}

if (Manad == 2) { // you may wanna put this if else statement inside the previous else
    System.out.print("Ange Dag");
    Dag = scanner1.nextInt();
    if (Dag > 0 && Dag < 29) {
        System.out.print("Korrekt Datum");
    }
}
else { // for now, this is called every time Mannad != 2 
    System.out.print("Felaktig Dag i Månaden");
}

if (Manad == 4 || Manad == 6 || Manad == 9 || Manad == 11) { 
    // put this if else statement inside else that belongs to Manad == 2
    System.out.println("Ange Dag");
    Dag = scanner1.nextInt();
    if (Dag > 0 && Dag < 31) {
        System.out.print("Korrekt Datum");
    }
}
else {// for now, this is called every time Manad != 4,6,9, or 11
    System.out.print("Felaktig Dag i Månaden");

    scanner1.close();

}
```

Comment: @forgivenson said the opposite a bit down

"Check the nesting of your if statements again. Your if(Manad == 2) is inside your if(Manad == 1 || ....), which doesn't allow Manad == 2, so that if statement will never be reached."

So which one is it, is it nested in and needs to be taken out or vice versa?

Comment: if Manad doesn't satisfy if(Manad ==1 || ...) then the else after it is called so if you put if(Manad == 2) statement inside that else it will always be checked  as long as Manad != 1,3,5....

Comment: same thing with if(Manad ==4 ||....) if you put it inside the else statement that belongs to if(Manad == 2), it will be always reached as long as if(Manad ==1 || ...) and if(Manad == 2) were not satisfied.