# Variable value playing up in if statement

Tags: java, if-statement

I am very new to java and my `if` statements don't seem to be assigning values to variables. I would really appreciate some help. The output is always `1000`

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.00");

    // Defines amount and bonus
    double amount; 
    double bonus;

    bonus = 0;

    amount = Double.parseDouble(txtAmountEarnt.getText());

    if (amount <= 2000) {
        bonus = 0;
    } 
    if (amount >2499 && amount <5000) {
        bonus = 500;
    } 
    if (5000 < amount); {
        bonus = 1000;
    }

    System.out.println(bonus);
    lblBonusAwarded.setText("Bonus awarded for earning $" + (df.format(amount)) + " = $" + (df.format(bonus)));
```

Comment: So, what's the complete output?

Comment: What is the input and corresponding output

Comment: And what should happen if the `amount` is in the interval 2001 to 2499?

Comment: Replace `if (5000 < amount); {` by `if (5000 < amount) {`. Note the `;`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Semicolon at end of 'if' statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14112515/semicolon-at-end-of-if-statement)

Answer (score 3):

There is a semicolon after the last if statement, which means the bonus gets set to 1000 no matter what.

Remove it and everything should be fine.

Comment: @a-price, might be a little late but, can you mark this as the Answer?

Answer (score 1):

Your current code could be simplified to one `if` block (with a nested `if-else`), you've already initialized `bonus` to `0` - so you don't need to explicitly do it again.

```
// Defines amount and bonus
double amount = Double.parseDouble(txtAmountEarnt.getText());
double bonus = 0;
if (amount > 2499) {
    if (amount > 5000) {
        bonus = 1000;
    } else {
        bonus = 500;
    } 
}
```