# Random color repeating

Tags: java, arrays, random, colors

How can I stop the color from being chosen in a row?

I'm trying to avoid repeating the same colors in a row chosen from the array. I have tried comparing if the colors are equal but haven't been able to skip the color when chosen randomly again.

```
Color color[]={Color.YELLOW,Color.MAGENTA,Color.BLACK,new Color(0x964B00),new Color(0xB57EDC)};

Random rand=new Random();
Color newColor = color[rand.nextInt(5)];

for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
    if(newColor.equals(color[i]));{
        newColor=color[rand.nextInt(5)];
    }
    myPanel.colorArray[myPanel.mouseDownGridX][myPanel.mouseDownGridY] = newColor;
    myPanel.repaint();
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to avoid repeating the same colors in a row chosen from the array.  I have tried comparing if the colors are equal but haven't been able to skip the color when chosen randomly again.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Why is it so far indented? I suspect you must have a lot of nesting.

Comment: Sorry I am a new user in StackOverflow.  My question is the comment below the code. How can I stop the same color from being chosen in a row?

Comment: @Dav1497 I cleaned up the question a bit, you can delete that comment with your actual question.

Comment: it is very unclear what you try to do and if i read your explanation and you code snippet

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Semicolon at end of 'if' statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14112515/semicolon-at-end-of-if-statement)

Comment: @Tom good catch :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not very clear and your current code shows a small selection size that will repeat often. This is a possible solution if your question is understand as:

> How to create a random number where the new number is not the previous one?

(note: code is from scratch - it should show the main idea in `randomExclude`)

```
Color color[]={Color.YELLOW,Color.MAGENTA,Color.BLACK,new Color(0x964B00),new Color(0xB57EDC)};

// remember the previous color somehow
int previousColorIndex = 0;

// -----

newColorIndex = randomExclude(previousColorIndex)

myPanel.colorArray[myPanel.mouseDownGridX][myPanel.mouseDownGridY] = color[newColorIndex];
myPanel.repaint();

previousColorIndex = newColorIndex

// -----

public static int randomExclude(int previous)
{
  Random rand=new Random();
  int random =rand.nextInt(5);

  if(previous == random)
    {
        return randomExclude(previous);
    } 
  }

  return random;
}
```

Comment: @Dav1497 if this answer solved your problem, please accept this answer: click at the grey checkmark on the left side of the answer.