# Java else if and scanner

Tags: java

I'm new in Java and more familiar with c++

```
import java.util.Scanner; 
class Test{ 
public static void main(String args[]){
Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in); 
 System.out.println("Pick option:\n 1-Option one\n 2-Option two");
 int x= sc.nextInt();
if (x=1);
{
System.out.println("You select option one");
}
else if(x=2);{
        System.out.println("You select option two");
}
else{
System.out.println("Please select option one or two by typing 1 or 2");}                 

} 
}
```

What should look like:

Pick option:

```
1- Option one
2- Option two
```

//User type 1:

```
You select option one.
```

//User type 2:

```
You select option two.
```

//User type anything else

```
Please select option one or two by typing 1 or 2.
```

How i can do that with java code.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: `=` is an assignment.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Semicolon at end of 'if' statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14112515/semicolon-at-end-of-if-statement)

Comment: Also `;` terminates the statement. So `if (x=1);` doesn't do anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `==` to copmare not use `=` and `;` after `if` statment not correct.

You can see the code after edit like this:

```
    import java.util.Scanner; 
    class Test{ 
    public static void main(String args[]){
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in); 
     System.out.println("Pick option:\n 1-Option one\n 2-Option two :");
     int x= sc.nextInt();
    if (x==1)
    {
    System.out.println("You select option one");
    }
    else if(x==2){
            System.out.println("You select option two");
    }
    else{
    System.out.println("Please select option one or two by typing 1 or 2");
}                 

    } 
    }
```