# System.IO.Exception : the directory name is invalid

Tags: filedialog, system.io.file

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gY3KS.png)i want to save to save a selected file in a specific folder. For that, i used a normal  FileDialog. Additional, the main aim is that the opened file which will be open with this FileDialog, must be saved automatically in the chosen folder. But i get a System.IO.Exception which says that the directory name is invalid.

Can you help me to find out where is the problem ? I guess that there is a problem with my code statement.. Do you have any ideas or other suggestions for writing such a code ?
[The code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MPeLQ.png)

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

I just found this [Semicolon at end of 'if' statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14112515/semicolon-at-end-of-if-statement).  It says having the semi-colon after your if statment will make it not act as an if statement basically.  Read it and remove that semi colon too!

**Original Answer**

Modify your code to explicitly get the directory name and check if the directory exists before trying to use it.  You can do this using `new File("<path>")` and checking that with `.exists()` and `.isDirectory()`.

You can create the directory with `.mkdirs()` as well if it isn't there so that you can copy files into it after that.

This will help you spot errors in your name as well.  I suspect your path is probably just bad / malformed.  I'd log it out before the checks to make it more obvious.