# Why equals() in if condition let everything in?

Tags: java

My task is to create function which returns true if string parameter contains 1,2 or 3 "e" characters, for loop is needed. It looks like equals() method passes everything in and increases counter whenever sLetter = "e" or not. Or maybe problem is somewhere else?

```
static boolean checkLetter (String paramOne){
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= paramOne.length() - 1; i++) {
        char letter = paramOne.charAt(i);
        String sLetter = Character.toString(letter);

        if (sLetter.equals("e"));
        {
            count++;
        }
    }

    System.out.print((count >= 1) && (count <= 3));
    return (count >= 1) && (count <= 3);
}
```

Comment: This article can help you:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767372/string-equals-versus

Comment: What problem? Also `letter == 'e'` and `if (sLetter.equals("e"));` has a really bad typo. Remove the semicolon.

Comment: Code looks correct, but you could just check to see if letter == 'e' instead of converting to a string.

Comment: Typo - you've got a semi-colon at the end of your `if` statement.

Comment: And where are some crucial informations like eg INPUT and actual OUTPUT ??

Comment: If you use a good IDE (e.g. Eclipse), it would give you this warning at the end of the `if` statement: **Empty control-flow statement**

Comment: More precisely, your if statement is followed by **an empty statement** (a single semicolon). Everything within the curly brackets are just part of a normal **code block**.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have an extra semicolon ";" on the if statement, so nothing happens if it's true and the count always goes up

change

```
 if (sLetter.equals("e"));
 {
   count++;
 }
```

to

```
 if (sLetter.equals("e")) {
   count++;
 }
```

Also you can simplify the logic by doing

```
if (letter == 'e') {
   count++;
}
```

Comment: Vote to close.  Don't answer questions this simple.

Comment: its in the comments already and for closing.

Comment: @Makoto  Why?  This is not obvious to a new developer.  Shouldn't we be helping folks like this instead of ignoring new users?

Comment: It's a typo which won't be of any value to anyone else in any meaningful way considering how much Google-able material already exists on it.

Comment: Maybe it should be closed as duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14112515/semicolon-at-end-of-if-statement instead of saying it's off topic

Answer (score -1):

Remove the semicolon from the end of the if statement.

```
static boolean checkLetter (String paramOne){
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= paramOne.length() - 1; i++) {
        char letter = paramOne.charAt(i);
        String sLetter = Character.toString(letter);

        if (sLetter.equals("e"))
        {
            count++;
        }
    }

    System.out.print((count >= 1) && (count <= 3));
    return (count >= 1) && (count <= 3);
}
```

Comment: Its typo issue..

Comment: Vote to close.  Don't answer questions this simple.