# Java comparing 10<-5 gets true

Tags: java

i'm learning java and got a problem, I have an max/min exercise and tried the code bellow, for positive numbers it work fine, but when i try negative numbers the things got messy.

If you enter 5 you get min = 5 and max = 5, if you enter 10 after, you get min = 5 max = 10, so far so good, but if you type -5, you get min = -5 and max = -5, and things still get weirder, if you type 7, you get min =-5 and max = 7.

Can someone explain why this happens?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int ctrl;
    int min = 0;
    int max = 0;
    boolean hasNextInt;
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int counter = 0;
    while (true) {
        System.out.println("Enter your number:");
        hasNextInt = scanner.hasNextInt();  
        if(hasNextInt) {
            ctrl = scanner.nextInt();
            if(counter == 0) {
                min = ctrl;
                max = ctrl;
                counter ++;
            }
            if(min>ctrl)
                min = ctrl;
            if(max<ctrl);
                max = ctrl;
            System.out.println("Minimum Number entered: " + min);
            System.out.println("Maximum Number entered: " + max);
            System.out.println("");
            scanner.nextLine();
        }else {
            System.out.println("Invalid Number. Program stop working.");
            break;
        }
    }
    scanner.close();
}
```

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14112515/semicolon-at-end-of-if-statement

Comment: `if(max<ctrl);` exactly does nothing, meaning that the following line (`max = ctrl;`) is always executed.

Comment: Remove the `;` after the `if(max<ctrl)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if(max<ctrl);
  max = ctrl;
```

That indentation is highly misleading.

Use an IDE that does code formatting. What you really wrote is

```
if(max<ctrl){}
max = ctrl;
```

Also avoid `if`/`else`/`for` etc without `{}`.