# How can I stop my character Going Up Automatically?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Why my character going up automatically though I'm not pressing any button?
I want to control my player jump movement.
But I cant do it.
What is the solution?
Please explain.
Can you also suggest how can I customise my jump, like jump twice? etc

```
public class movement: MonoBehaviour {
  public float speed = 10;

  private Rigidbody2D rb;

  public float jumpSpeed = 1;

  void Start() {
    rb = GetComponent < Rigidbody2D > ();
  }

  // Update is called once per frame
  void Update() {
    Jump();
    var inputX = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    Vector3 movement = new Vector3(inputX, 0, 0) * speed;
    movement *= Time.deltaTime;
    transform.Translate(movement);

    Vector3 characterScale = transform.localScale;
    if (inputX < 0) {
      transform.localScale = new Vector3(5, transform.localScale.y, transform.localScale.z);
    }

    if (inputX > 0) {
      transform.localScale = new Vector3(-5, transform.localScale.y, transform.localScale.z);
    }
  }

  void Jump() {
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space));
    rb.velocity = Vector2.up * jumpSpeed;
  }
}
```

Comment: You have a `;` after an `if` statement => the line `rb.velocity = Vector2.up * jumpSpeed;` is executed **always** ... I'd say this is a **Typo**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is with the `if` statement in `Jump`. If there are no curly braces after an if statement, only the first statement is enclosed within the `if`.

```
if (something)
    do_stuff(); // This will execute if something evaluates to true
    do_other_stuff(); // This will execute no matter what
```

In your case, the next statement looks like this:

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
    ;
```

The semicolon is an empty statement. Then, the second line `rb.velocity = Vector2.up * jumpSpeed;` executes normally.

[This is in java, but the same logic applies to C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14112515/semicolon-at-end-of-if-statement)

Proper code will look like:

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)) {
    rb.velocity = Vector2.up * jumpSpeed;
}
```

Note that there is no semicolon on the line of the if statement.

Comment: if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
    ;   . How do i code it correctly?  i get syntax error while placing my bracket...

Comment: I edited the answer to give an example of the correct syntax