# JAVA: How to compare child class in a List

Tags: java, inheritance, extends, instanceof

So I created a parent class : Animals

```
public class Animals {

   private String type;

   public String getType(){
       return this.type;
   }
}
```

And I then created different child class like horse, bear, dog etc that extends Animals.

I then created a List <  Animals   > list which can contain object which are either from horse class, bear, etc.

But I've been struggling to create a method that could tell me if yes or no my list contains for i.e any bear (an object from Bear Class).

I tried so many things.

1. horse.getClass() returns nothing
2. if i do a

   ```
    Horse h = new Horse();
   ```

   System.out.print(h instanceof Bear);

---> it returns true which is wrong.

3. Same thing with equals.
4. I also created a String attribute in each child class so I can compare the string instead but Java doesn't read them as string somehow.

I am so lost.

Comment: You must be doing something wrong with your tests or class hierarchy because the thing you labelled '2' will not return true. What is the class declaration for the `Horse` and `Bear` class?

Comment: @BenAnderson 
I have nothing inside my class except this:

`public class Bear extends Animals {

    private String type = "bear";
   
}

I created my list inside another model Class 

public class Cell {
    private List<Animals> contents = new ArrayList<Anmals>();

    public List<Animals> getCellContents(){
        return contents;
    }
    public boolean hasBear(){
        for(int i=0; i< contents.size(); ++i){
            Animals a = contents.get(i);
            if(a instanceof Bear);
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }`

Comment: possible that the fact you have done `++i` instead of `i++` is causing issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with your if statement.

```
if(a instanceof Bear);
    return true;
```

You have ended your if statement with a semicolon which means its an empty statement and the next line `return true` is always executed. Remove the semicolon after the if statement.

Read more here: [Semicolon at end of 'if' statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14112515/semicolon-at-end-of-if-statement)

Comment: OMG I can't believe I put that dang ";"  Thank you so much