# What does a while loop that ends with a semicolon mean?

Tags: java

I came across this piece of code but I'm not familiar with this while loop syntax.

```
while(i < j){
    while(distance(arr[++i]) < distance(p));
    while(distance(arr[--j]) > distance(p));
    if(i < j){
        swap(arr, i, j);
    }
}
```

I've never seen a while loop without braces that end in semicolons. What do they mean?

Comment: Nothing other than no body is present as none is needed. The functionality is all in the loop condition. A terminating semicolon is often a mistake by beginners (then they wonder why the body doesn't execute) but not in this case

Comment: you could, instead of a semicolon, use empty braces (`while (condition) { }`), same result

Comment: Duplicate of [Semicolon at end of 'if' statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14112515/semicolon-at-end-of-if-statement)

Comment: @user16320675 perhaps more readable

Comment: if you want to Google it, search for "Java empty statement".  It is also known as a "null statement".

Answer (score -1):

`while(cond);`

is the same as

`while(cond) {}`

Comment: I have removed your final comment. It works because a while is followed by a statement or a block, and just `;` is considered a valid statement in Java (and empty statement).

Comment: Regardless that your answer is correct or not, you are encouraged to edit it to explain why this is the best answer to the question.